# How to group array elements in PHP and return as JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have bookings table with set of time range. Each range produces a new row in database. When I query all the bookings with a specific `booking_id` then I get all the results in 4 arrays. What I would like to do is have them listed all under one booking_id.

Currently I get this JSON returned:

```
{  
    "status":"success",
    "data":[  
        {  
            "first_name":"John",
            "user_name":"john-k",
            "booking_id":"3521AE",
            "nanny_id":1,
            "status":0,
            "amount":"36.00",
            "parent_id":15,
            "date":"2017-07-02",
            "start_time":"12:00:00",
            "end_time":"13:00:00"
        },
        {  
            "first_name":"John",
            "user_name":"john-k",
            "booking_id":"3521AE",
            "nanny_id":1,
            "status":0,
            "amount":"36.00",
            "parent_id":15,
            "date":"2017-07-02",
            "start_time":"13:00:00",
            "end_time":"14:00:00"
        },
        {  
            "first_name":"John",
            "user_name":"john-k",
            "booking_id":"3521AE",
            "nanny_id":1,
            "status":0,
            "amount":"36.00",
            "parent_id":15,
            "date":"2017-07-02",
            "start_time":"14:00:00",
            "end_time":"15:00:00"
        },
        {  
            "first_name":"John",
            "user_name":"john-k",
            "booking_id":"3521AE",
            "nanny_id":1,
            "status":0,
            "amount":"36.00",
            "parent_id":15,
            "date":"2017-07-02",
            "start_time":"15:00:00",
            "end_time":"16:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to have is like this:

```
{  
    "status":"success",
    "data":[  
        {  
            "first_name":"John",
            "user_name":"john-k",
            "booking_id":"3521AE",
            "nanny_id":1,
            "status":0,
            "amount":"36.00",
            "parent_id":15,
            "date":"2017-07-02",
            "times":[
              {
                "start_time":"12:00:00",
                "end_time":"16:00:00"
              }
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this? I tried to use `foreach` in my Controller to group them by booking_id but this did not work at all. Here is my Controller:

```
  $booking_id = Input::get('booking_id');
  $booking_array = [];
  $bookings = Nanny_bookings::selectRaw('first_name, user_name, nanny_bookings.booking_id, nanny_id, status, amount, nanny_bookings.parent_id, date, start_time, end_time')
  ->join('booking_confirmations', 'booking_confirmations.booking_id', '=', 'nanny_bookings.booking_id')
  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'nanny_bookings.nanny_id')
  ->where('nanny_bookings.booking_id', $booking_id)
  ->groupBy('nanny_bookings.booking_id','nanny_id', 'nanny_bookings.parent_id', 'date', 'status', 'amount', 'start_time', 'end_time')
  ->get();


  foreach ($bookings as $key => &$entry) {
      $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']][$key] = $entry;
  }

  $response = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'data' => $booking
  );

  //if request is ajax
  if (Request::ajax()) {
    return Response::json($response);
  }
```

Comment: Where is the `foreach`?

Comment: @jeroen posted it.

Comment: why downvote? no explanation

Answer (score 0):

That can be a start, for replace your actual foreach.

> **This code don't work if you have holes between times**

```
// Function to check if a time is before or after another one
function isOp($operator, $existingTime, $newTime) {
    $newTimeInt = (int) str_replace(':', '', $newTime);
    $existingTimeInt = (int) str_replace(':', '', $existingTime);
    if ($operator === 'before') {
        return ($newTimeInt < $existingTimeInt);
    } else if ($operator === 'after') {
        return ($newTimeInt > $existingTimeInt);
    }
}


foreach ($bookings as $key => $entry) {
    // Check if booking already exist
    if (array_key_exists($entry['booking_id'], $booking_array)) {
        // Booking already exist -> add time
        if (isOp('before', $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['times'][0]['start_time'], $entry['start_time'])) {
            $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['times'][0]['start_time'] = $entry['start_time'];
        }
        if (isOp('after', $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['times'][0]['end_time'], $entry['end_time'])) {
            $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['times'][0]['end_time'] = $entry['end_time'];
        }
    } else {
        // Create booking
        $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']] = $entry;
        // Remove start/end time, not needed on booking level
        unset($booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['start_time']);
        unset($booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['end_time']);
        // Add first time
        $booking_array[$entry['booking_id']]['times'] = array(
            array(
                "start_time"=>$entry["start_time"],
                "end_time"=>$entry["start_time"]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I get this error: Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Models\Dashboard\Nanny\Bookings\Nanny_bookings has no effect

Comment: Oups, a small mistake in foreach loop (wrong character) `foreach ($bookings as $key => $entry)`, remove the &